# Get onAppear behaviour from list in ScrollView in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

When creating a `List` view `onAppear` triggers for elements in that list the way you would expect: As soon as you scroll to that element the `onAppear` triggers. However, I'm trying to implement a horizontal list like this

```swift
ScrollView(.horizontal) { 
   HStack(spacing: mySpacing) {
      ForEach(items) { item in 
         MyView(item: item)
            .onAppear { \\do something }
      } 
   }
}
```

Using this method the `onAppear` triggers for all items at once, that is to say: immediately, but I want the same behavior as for a `List` view. How would I go about doing this? Is there a manual way to trigger onAppear, or control when views load?

Why I want to achieve this: I have made a custom `Image` view that loads an image from an URL only when it appears (and substitutes a placeholder in the mean time), this works fine for a `List` view, but I'd like it to also work for my horizontal 'list'.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Also, does `onAppear` inside `List` still work for you?

Comment: onAppear called only when view is appeared on screen. In ScrollView it called without appearing on screen

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm still having the exact same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately I too still have the same issue. It’s not elegant, but I’ve implemented my own custom ‘onAppear’ function which fetches the coordinates of the items and calculates whether it is visible using the screen boundaries.

Comment: @M.Koot could you show how you did this, it would be an interesting answer for this post :)

Comment: I just have an idea. It might be solved by getting the views positions. when they are at a position you want, do something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per SwiftUI 2.0 (XCode 12 beta 1) this is finally natively solved:
In a `LazyHStack` (or any other grid or stack with the Lazy prefix) elements will only initialise (and therefore trigger `onAppear`) when they appear on screen.

Answer (score 4):

Here is possible approach how to do this (tested/worked with Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2)

Demo: (just show dynamically first & last visible cell in scrollview)

[image: demo]

A couple of important `View` extensions

```
extension View {
    func rectReader(_ binding: Binding<CGRect>, in space: CoordinateSpace) -> some View {
        self.background(GeometryReader { (geometry) -> AnyView in
            let rect = geometry.frame(in: space)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                binding.wrappedValue = rect
            }
            return AnyView(Rectangle().fill(Color.clear))
        })
    }
}

extension View {
    func ifVisible(in rect: CGRect, in space: CoordinateSpace, execute: @escaping (CGRect) -> Void) -> some View {
        self.background(GeometryReader { (geometry) -> AnyView in
            let frame = geometry.frame(in: space)
            if frame.intersects(rect) {
                execute(frame)
            }
            return AnyView(Rectangle().fill(Color.clear))
        })
    }
}
```

And a demo view of how to use them with cell views being in scroll view

```
struct TestScrollViewOnVisible: View {
    @State private var firstVisible: Int = 0
    @State private var lastVisible: Int = 0
    @State private var visibleRect: CGRect = .zero
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("<< \(firstVisible)")
                Spacer()
                Text("\(lastVisible) >> ")
            }
            Divider()
            band()
        }
    }
    
    func band() -> some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            HStack(spacing: 10) {
                ForEach(0..<50) { i in
                    self.cell(for: i)
                        .ifVisible(in: self.visibleRect, in: .named("my")) { rect in
                            print(">> become visible [\(i)]")
                            
                            // do anything needed with visible rects, below is simple example
                            // (w/o taking into account spacing)
                            if rect.minX <= self.visibleRect.minX && self.firstVisible != i {
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    self.firstVisible = i
                                }
                            } else
                            if rect.maxX >= self.visibleRect.maxX && self.lastVisible != i {
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    self.lastVisible = i
                                }
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        .coordinateSpace(name: "my")
        .rectReader(self.$visibleRect, in: .named("my"))
    }

    func cell(for idx: Int) -> some View {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
            .fill(Color.yellow)
            .frame(width: 80, height: 60)
            .overlay(Text("\(idx)"))
    }
}
```

Comment: this is working in iOS13 and it's great. But would know why it is now working in iOS14?

Comment: This is working perfectly fine for my issue (in iOS 17) where LazyHStack is not a suitable solution. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you want to achieve can be done with LazyHStack.

```
ScrollView {
    LazyVStack {
        ForEach(1...100, id: \.self) { value in
            Text("Row \(value)")
                .onAppear {
                     // Write your code for onAppear here.
                 }
        }
    }
}
```