# Detect which image or struct is visible on a carousel

Tags: ios, swiftui, carousel

I would like to know if there's any easy way to detect which image or struct of a carousel is actually visible on screen.
I tried something like this but it seems to consider that my struct actually appears on the screen even when it's not visible:

```
ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
    HStack {
        myFirstStruct().onAppear {
            print("Struct 1 shown")
        }.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)

        mySecondStruct().onAppear {
            print("Struct 2 shown")
        }.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
    }
}
```

Comment: Next can be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/60643762/12299030 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/62588295/12299030.

Comment: Thanks @Asperi! I didn't find the LazyHStack solution during my previous researches. It works very well.