# How do I know a scrollview element is about to leave/entering the screen, so I can create an animation

Tags: swiftui

I have a vertical scrollView with a lot of items. As the user scrolls I want to do some nice effect, for example, like a carousel or something. In fact, less dramatic, just the cells being shifted to the right as they are cut as the scroll out of view.

This is what I have to test.

```
ScrollView {
  ForEach(0...50) { item in
    GeometryReader { geometry in
      Text(item)
       .onChange(of: geometry.frame(in: .named("xxx")), perform: { value in
          if item == 1 {
            print(value.minY)}
          })
    }
   }
  }
  .coordinateSpace(name: "xxx")
```

I have added this `coordinateSpace` and this `.onChange`, to see what is happening with one element in particular, element number 1.

I see number one's `value.minY` goes from 0 to -400, if I scroll up. When Y is 0, is when this element is fully on view.

But if I have N elements on that view, it will be very complex to know when every element is entering the view. At least I am not seeing how.

The idea is to apply an effect like a shift, rotation or whatever, when the element starts to go off view and unwind the effect when the element is full on view.

How?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/60643762/12299030?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apologize if I misread your question, but your just trying to animate the objects when the come on or off the screen based on their location within the coordinate space? If so, here's an example of how to do it. It's basically what you had except you can use the geometry immediately on modifiers and don't need the .onChange.

The below code has a top & bottom threshold, calculates each item's % into the threshold and then updates modifiers accordingly.

```swift
    import SwiftUI
    
    struct ScrollAnimationView: View {
    
        var body: some View {
            ScrollView {
                ForEach(0..<50) { item in
                    GeometryReader { geometry in
                        Text("NUMBER \(item), PERCENT: \(getPercentOfAnimation(geo: geometry))")
                            .font(.headline)
                            .offset(x: getPercentOfAnimation(geo: geometry) * UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
                            .opacity(1.0 - Double(getPercentOfAnimation(geo: geometry)))
                            .rotationEffect(
                                Angle(degrees: 10 * Double(getPercentOfAnimation(geo: geometry)))
                            )
                            .scaleEffect(1.0 - getPercentOfAnimation(geo: geometry))
                    }
                }
            }
            .coordinateSpace(name: "xxx")
        }
        
        func getPercentOfAnimation(geo: GeometryProxy) -> CGFloat {
            let threshold: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.4
            let currentY: CGFloat = geo.frame(in: .named("xxx")).minY
    
            if currentY <  threshold {
                return 1 - currentY / threshold
            }
            let topThreshold: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.6
            if currentY > topThreshold {
                return (currentY - topThreshold) / threshold
            }
            return 0
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: simply brilliant. Now I see how it works... thanks.